# php+mysql Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

installed 
XAMPP for Windows
v5.6.19 (PHP 5.6.19) from [apache friend](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

using dreamweaver cs 6 and windows 10

tried so many different method. and not work, and also working with phpinfo() i want to throw out reading this. please help

uncommented

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

removing backslash

```
extension_dir="C:xampp\php\ext"
```

reading

```
phpinfo()
```

see all of the same question and googling. please help

Comment: Which version of PHP you are using ?

Comment: extension_dir="C:xampp\php\ext" this line is not proper. it should be extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.19 @BikashPaul

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu just tried this still no luck

Comment: Did you restart APACHE after this changes

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu stop and start exit and back at it again, its more than a restart :/

Comment: yes, it is same as restart, but you did not mention it. Check you log it will suggest you where is the issue.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu how to check? how to log it?

Comment: http://www.codeasite.com/index.php/linux-a-apache/94-how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files check the link to get log file location

Answer (score 1):

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: u mean my php version is too old and i should get the new one? how do i get that?

Comment: No, it just means you can't use mysql_connect. Instead you can use mysqli_connect. I mean use mysqli or pdo extensions.

Comment: You can use this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) to know more about connecting via mysqli or PDO. Try connecting to database using this tutorials